# Error 404 Object not found! before start to handle URL on index

Tags: php, windows, .htaccess, xampp, url-routing

I did my own PHP project and all request are handled right except when I go to error page.

**URL format**: http://project/controller/action

**Edit:** If i go to http://project/error, everything is fine, the controller exists and is created correctly.

The problem is only if i go to http://project/error/**whatever** (e.g: http://project/error/pageNotFound), throws me: *Object not found! ... Error 404* **before** to start execute my index.php. I did:

```
die("first line execute");
```

And throws error 404 first, doesn't matter if the action exists or not, i can't handle URL.

¿Perhaps its an .htaccess error? Because nothing execute. I've got this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I don't know, thank you very much for your time.

**Edit 2:** Tested with xampp (VirtualHost) on windows 10

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please show the entire error message, which includes both the file name and line number on which the error occurred. Showing that code as well will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks! Error: 
Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404.

Error controller exists. No error line because its a server error

Comment: After trying a lot of things I think it has to do with the **error** word in URL. I've created a new controller with random name but exactly with the same content as the error file and works great.

If someone knows something tell me please.